# UWP button stretch and left align

Tags: xaml

Hi how to make this button:

```
                        <Button x:Name="StartButton" Background="Transparent" Click="StartButton_Click">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE768; " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="Start"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
```

to fill its parent (horizontally) and to have its content aligned left?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? It's difficult to diagnose the problem with **only** the `Button` code.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer:

```
<Button x:Name="StartButton" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock FontSize="18">
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE768; "/>
        <Run Text="Start"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: Indeed, `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` was the key for me doing similar work, in 2023 :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the expected result, I recommend using `<Run>` to define the inlines of your `TextBlock`

This should look like :

```
<Button x:Name="StartButton" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Click="StartButton_Click">
    <TextBlock FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Run FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE768; "/>
        <Run Text="Start"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the button doesn't fill its parent. Although it is aligned left.

Comment: I may have forgotten the `Button`s own Alignment. Code edited

Comment: I posted correct answer. There should be HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" and it is not necessary to set HorizontalAlignment for TextBlock. However, thank you very much as you shown me the way.